# RAILS_ENV=production rails s not working - wrong number of arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth

When I run `RAILS_ENV=development rails s` my app works fine. But when I run `RAILS_ENV=production rails s` I get the message:

```
christophecompaq@ubuntu:~/FunkyApp$ RAILS_ENV=production rails s
DEPRECATION WARNING: require "activerecord" is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 3. Use require "active_record" instead. (called from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/activerecord.rb:2)
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.2.3 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/omniauth-1.1.0/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:136:in `initialize': Received wrong number of arguments. [nil] (ArgumentError)
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:43:in `new'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:43:in `build'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:113:in `build'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:282:in `inject'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:113:in `each'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:113:in `inject'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:113:in `build'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:470:in `build_middleware_stack'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:31
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `run_initializers'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `send'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from /home/christophecompaq/FunkyApp/config/environment.rb:5
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /home/christophecompaq/FunkyApp/config.ru:4
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
    from /home/christophecompaq/FunkyApp/config.ru:1:in `new'
    from /home/christophecompaq/FunkyApp/config.ru:1
christophecompaq@ubuntu:~/FunkyApp$
```

With my limited Rails knowledge, I think I figure it out right when I say there's a problem with the omniauth gem - strategy.rb, line 136, specifically.

But I've never, ever, changed anything in my var/lib/gems folder. And when I compare my strategy.rb against the one on github: https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/blob/v1.1.0/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb#L124 I get the exact same file - even the formatting is identical.

I have backups of my app and even when I go into those backup folders and do `RAILS_ENV=production rails s` I get the exact same error message - which would lead me to believe it's some core dependency/gem file issue, not some configuration/deploy thing I accidentlly changed in my app folder. (although I'm probably wrong!...) Everything was working fine up to about 3 weeks ago - no `rails s` errors at all

I'm just throwing ideas out there, but something maybe in .bashrc, .bash_profile?...I don't know. Any help would be appreciated!

**Edit: adding my gemfile, below:**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.3'
gem 'rake', '~> 10.0.4'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.11'
gem 'json', '~> 1.7.3'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'compass-rails', '~> 1.0.1'
  gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 2.0.2'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'therubyracer', '~> 0.10.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platform => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
  gem 'jquery-fileupload-rails'
end

gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 2.0.2'
gem 'inherited_resources', '~> 1.3.1'
gem 'simple_form', '~> 2.0.2'
gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.0.3'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '~> 0.0.7'
gem 'has_scope', '~> 0.5.1'
gem "best_in_place", "~> 1.1.2"

gem 'devise', '~> 2.0.4'
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'linkedin'
gem 'omnicontacts', '~> 0.2.3'
gem 'SystemTimer', '~> 1.2.3'
gem 'resque', '~> 1.20.0'
gem 'resque-scheduler', :require => 'resque_scheduler'
gem 'rest-client', '~> 1.6.7'
gem 'rest-graph', '~> 2.0.1'

gem 'geokit', '=1.6.5'
gem 'geokit-rails3', '~> 0.1.5'
gem 'memcache-client'

gem 'forgery', '~> 0.5.0'
gem 'factory_girl_rails', '~> 1.7.0'
gem "amoeba", "~> 1.2.1"

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'ruby-debug'

group :development do
  gem 'mongrel'
  gem 'pry-rails'
  gem 'quiet_assets'
  gem 'email_spec'
  gem 'capistrano', '~> 2.12.0'
  gem 'capistrano-ext', '~> 1.2.1'
  gem 'rvm-capistrano', '~> 1.2.1'
  gem 'ruby-debug-base', '=0.10.4'
  gem 'ruby-debug', '=0.10.4'
  gem 'annotate'
  gem 'letter_opener', :git => 'https://github.com/ryanb/letter_opener.git'
  gem 'localtunnel'
end

group :test do
  gem 'cucumber-rails', '~> 1.3.0', :require => false
  gem 'capybara-webkit', '~> 0.11.0'
  gem 'headless', '~> 0.3.1'
  gem 'database_cleaner', '~> 0.7.2'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 2.9.0'
  gem 'email_spec'
end
```

Comment: What happens when you try `rails s -e production`? That's the documented way to supply the environment to Rails.

Comment: I get the same error.

Comment: Can you post your Gemfile?

Comment: Hi, I pasted my gemfile into the question, above.

Comment: Thought it might be a gem grouping issue, but that looks fine.  Did you review this ticket?  https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/issues/525  Possibly something with your initializer - maybe you are only setting up the options within development.rb

Comment: yes, I looked at it there, but not sure I understand it. My environments/development.rb has no such code or anything similar. Is there another development.rb I should be looking at? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the environment using  `bin/rails db:environment:set RAILS_ENV=production`